# Not able to add visually hidden elements to IList (Selenium, C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, dom, selector

I am not sure those elements are hidden, just the class name says it. Also, all the class names include spaces (not sure how to handle this too).

I tried to take those elements using CSS Selector, Xpath, ClassName and always one and the same - `IList` has 0 elements.

```
IList<IWebElement> input1 = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("mat-checkbox-input.cdk-visually-hidden"));
```

What I want to do is to add those checkboxes in a list before the operation of checking them and then after this operation, to add them in another list and in the end to assert comparing them.

```
<input class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden xh-highlight" type="checkbox" id="stages-9999600009-checkbox-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false">
<input class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden xh-highlight" type="checkbox" id="stages-89999600000-checkbox-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false">
```

**Dom**

[image: Dom]

Answer (score 0):

Finding elements by className will fail, because Selenium wont support class names with spaces

Xpath should be working,assuming you have written a correct xpath

From the question you've provided Css Selector. The issue with your css selector is, you forgot to add a dot in the beginning. Class Names should be prefixed with dots else css will assume it as tagName.

You've written like `(By.CssSelector("mat-checkbox-input.cdk-visually-hidden")`

It should be  `(By.CssSelector(".mat-checkbox-input.cdk-visually-hidden")`

Refer

https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/css-selector-selenium-webdriver-tutorial/

https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Comment: Thank you! I actually know that and thought that I have tried it, but maybe somehow missed it somewhere in the hundred selectors I tried :D